# Is my 18.04 Ubuntu Hard Drive Encrypted

Tags: encryption, drive

Not sure if my hard drive is encrypted. How do I confirm my hard drive was encrypted during Ubuntu 18.04 installation?

Comment: Do you get a password prompt to decrypt it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Linux Mint and I have encrypted all my hard drive. but on Ubuntu it should be quite the same I guess.

Using the terminal, you can enter:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It should return some informations like this:

```
Disk /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: 464.6 GiB, 498799214592 bytes, 974217216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: 456.6 GiB, 490301554688 bytes, 957620224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: 7.9 GiB, 8493465600 bytes, 16588800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

You can notice the `sda3_crypt` that is taking almost all the size of my hard drive. This means that my hard drive is fully encrypted.

Without using the terminal, you can use `Disks` or `Gparted` to have a view of your hard drive. On my computer, it looks like:
[image]

Again, you see that the LUKS partition covering almost the entire hard drive is encrypted.

Finally, you can also check it by running Ubuntu on a LiveUSB. Your internal hard drive should not be accessible without the passphrase.

Hope it answers your question.